# Difference in Mono.fromCallable And Mono.justOrEmpty

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

What is the different between the following two executions?

```
Mono.justOrEmpty(someFunction())
  .doOnNext(() -> doSomeTask()).subscribe();

Mono.fromCallable(() -> someFunction())
  .doOnNext(() -> doSomeTask()).subscribe();
```

Answer (score 5):

With `Mono.fromCallable`, the `Callable` is called lazily only when the resulting `Mono` is subscribed to.

(you can even rewrite your snippet to `Mono.fromCallable(this::someFunction)` if `someFunction` doesn't take any parameter)

With `Mono.justOrEmpty`, the value is captured immediately by the operator for future emission. So in effect here the `someFunction()` method is called immediately at construction.

Note that both of these variants will correctly deal with `someFunction()` returning `null` (unlike `Mono.just(...)`). In that case, the resulting `Mono` will simply complete (`onComplete` signal without `onNext`).

Note also that if the method is blocking and long running, it might be an antipattern in both cases. See https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking

Comment: Another important consideration is error handling. In case `someFunction` could throw exception `Mono.justOrEmpty` will not allow you to handle error as a part of the reactive flow (e.g using `onErrorResume`) because as @Simon mentioned "method is called immediately at construction" but `Mono.fromCallable` will work.

Answer (score 4):

With `Mono.fromCallable`, `someFunction` will be called when a subscription is made.

```
private static Integer someFunction() {
  System.out.println("calling someFunction");
  return 1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Mono<Integer> mono = Mono.fromCallable(ReactorApp2::someFunction)
                           .doOnNext(System.out::println);

  System.out.println("Subscribing...");

  mono.subscribe();
  mono.subscribe();
}

/*
Subscribing...
calling someFunction
1
calling someFunction
1
*/
```

With `Mono.justOrEmpty`, `someFunction` will be called only once.

```
private static Integer someFunction() {
  System.out.println("calling someFunction");
  return 1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Mono<Integer> mono = Mono.justOrEmpty(someFunction())
                           .doOnNext(System.out::println);

  System.out.println("Subscribing...");

  mono.subscribe();
  mono.subscribe();
}

/*
calling someFunction
Subscribing...
1
1
*/
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically using `Mono.fromCallable()` `Callable` emits the resulting value as `Mono`. `Mono.justOrEmpty()` only emits the specified item as `Mono` if it exists.

In the official docs `justOrEmpty` and `fromCallable` are described as follows:

### Mono.justOrEmpty()

> Create a new Mono that emits the specified item if non null otherwise only emits onComplete.

[image]

### Mono.fromCallable()

> Create a Mono producing its value using the provided Callable. If the Callable resolves to null, the resulting Mono completes empty.

[image]

If you need more detailed information about `Mono`, you can check the [official documentation.](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html)